# How to implement complex microservices?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, architecture, microservices

A have some questions about microservices using a complex cenario. For example, checkout.

I need to work with product's details, update inventory, user's details, taxes 
according with user's region, calculate final price and send the product. So i have the following services:

- ProductService;
- InventoryService;
- UserService;
- TaxesService;
- ShippingService;
- CheckoutService?

My first question, i need a new service (like CheckoutService) to do all this logic (and calculate final price)?

In case of yes, this new service will control the transaction (like two-phase commit)?

Every service have to be your own database? If my application runs in amazon environment, i need to have one instance of RDS for each service?

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, no matter what answers you get, none will be the perfect answer as a lot of this is subject to design and your own personal needs.

The steps I take when designing a complex microservices architecture follow suit closely with Domain Driven Design (DDD) and are as follows:

1. Define your domain (in your example, ECommerce seems to be your domain)
2. Determine on your immediate deliverables (in your example, the ability to add items to a cart and checkout)
3. Define your contextual boundaries (in your example, Checkout could be it's own contextual boundary and is probably fine grained enough. Anymore fine grained than checkout you are probably venturing into the nano-services territory which is not where you want to be)

Now you have contextual boundaries which will be your microservices. When it comes to implementing that contextual boundary, you need to break it down into it's own individual pieces. From your example, it appears you have

1. Price/Tax calculations
2. Inventory management
3. Order management

From there, you can then determine what functionality you require in each piece of the contextual boundary and break them up into presentation/controller, services, and repositories.

So for example, take Order Management. You would probably want something like:

- Order Service to handle the business logic and data mapping for orders
- Order Repository to pull data from your data store in regards to orders

If your Order Management needs are very complex with a lot of business rules, you might break it up into multiple services/repositories to suit those demands or maybe it would then deserve it's own contextual boundary...

I can't tell you how to do your checkout (you asked about calculating stuff and controlling the transaction). That design is however you decide to do it.

Once you have all that in place you can then determine your data store needs and your server needs. Initially, you probably don't have a ton of users, so each service could probably live on the same server in the same project and you could have a single database on it's own server. But make sure to write it all in a way that they can be broken out later so when you require the ability to handle more users through a distributed system, you can do so without rewriting a ton of code.

That's about as good of an answer as I can give you without knowing anything about what you're doing. I wouldn't take what I put here word for word and implement it, I would instead, take the advice here and go through the steps yourself to determine the design which best suits your needs.

**TL;DR**

1. Define your domain
2. Breakup your domain into contextual boundaries
3. Determine each piece of your contextual boundaries
4. Break those pieces up into presentation/controllers, services, and repositories.
5. Once that's all in place, determine your data store and server needs (starting out, likely a server for each of your data stores (e.g. SQL on a server and NoSQL/Blob on another), and a single server for your microservices. Then when you have more users to handle, distribute your microservices)

Good luck!